# Как в не зависимости от значения поля вернуть только 1 запись по каждому товару?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select a.name1, b.name2 
from table a join table b on a.id = b.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в не зависимости от значения поля name2 вернуть только 1 запись по каждому товару?

`distinct` нет, т.к. `name2` не повторяется.

`where b.name2 = 0` нет, т.к. не известно значение поля. Может быть любое значение.

Comment: само проще так: `select a.name1, (select top 1 name2 from table b where b.id = a.id) from table a`

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name1, MIN(b.name2) AS name2
from table a join table b on a.id = b.id
group by a.name1
```

Вместо `MIN` можно предусмотреть другую логику выбора значения `name2`.
Если логика не укладывается в аггрегатные функции - можно использовать `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select a.name1, b.name2 AS name2
from table a 
cross apply (select top 1 name2 from table b where a.id=b.id) b
```

Comment: Только не `outer apply`, а `cross apply`, т.к. в исходном запросе `join`, а не `left join`.

Comment: @i-one, согласен.